# Port connections details in informatica between 2 mappings residing in same respository and same folder

Tags: sql, oracle, repository, informatica-powercenter

I have two mappings : m_mapping_A and m_mapping_B
Columns(Ports) of target definition from m_mapping_A are being populated from source qualifier ports. -- Level 1
now, source qualifier ports of m_mapping_A are getting input ports from m_mapping_B -- Level2
I am able to get the input ports from informatica database by querying tabe rep_mapping_conn_ports for Level1 mapping but being defeated to get the actual source columns which is in mapping_B. 
Could someone help?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM REP_MAPPING_CONN_PORTS where TO_OBJECT_FIELD_NAME  like 'x_%'-- target column in mapping A starts from 'X_' , gives me the source port, now this port is getting input from mapping B, I need to get those actual source port.

Comment: I would like to get something like this :-map a source field to a target field with all sorts of transformation logic (include transformation type like lookup, joiner and logic, may be a DECODE) that it undergoes.

Comment: Can do manual backtrack from target to stage to source can get the info but its a tedious job when you have 300+ mappings and source of one mapping coming from target of another mapping. I am looking towards metadata queries, does anyone know these type of queries in this forum?